# Loop of JSON object with *ngFor (Angular 5)

Tags: arrays, json, angular, angular5, ngfor

I want to loop through an array of objects. but I could not do the loop to "purchases". 
This is the result that I have by console:

```
[{
  "createdAt": "Fri Aug 31 2018 15:19:03 GMT-0400 
    (Eastern Daylight Time)
  ", 
  "customer": {
    "address": "test",
    "lastname": "Carrio",
    "name": "Mabel",
    "phone": "786222222"
  },
  "purchases": {
    "0": {
      "product": {
        "categoryS": "-L9QdqynslyGy8Ft1G9z",
        "location": "en tienda",
        "name": "Memoria",
        "price": 12
      },
      "quantity": 3
    }
  },
  "totalPrice": 36,
  "uid": "fr0Yix3T2hMio3KzwAB1r6aJbZA2",
  "$key": "-LLGQAB3V_PRiW2v02bx"
}]
```

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.invoiceService.getInvoices().snapshotChanges().subscribe(data => {
      this.invoiceList = []

      data.forEach(element => {
          let x = element.payload.toJSON()
          this.invoiceList.push(x);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

list.component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let invoice of invoiceList">
  <td>{{invoice.customer.name}} {{invoice.customer.lastname}}</td>
  <td>{{invoice.totalPrice}}</td>
  <td>{{invoice.purchases.product.name}}</td>
  <--- Error 
</tr>
```

any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to convert the purchases element into array?

Comment: It would be nice if you refactor your Template code a bit as well. :)

Comment: with reference to your comment in the deleted answer ... ngFor only supports binding to iterables such as arrays ... not true ... see https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe introduced in ng6.1 ... but true if you are strictly referring to v5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component code needs refactoring. Here's how you can refactor it:

```
// First
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

// Then
ngOnInit() {
  this.invoiceService.getInvoices().snapshotChanges()
    .map(data => data.map(datum => datum.payload.toJSON()))
    .map(data => {
      return data.map(datum => {
        let purchases = [];
        for (let key in datum.purchases) {
          purchases.push(datum.purchases[key]);
        }
        datum.purchases = purchases;
        return datum;
      });
    })
    .subscribe(data => this.invoiceList = data);
}
```

Also, since doing something along the lines of `Object.0` will throw an error, you should be using the Array member access pattern. Your template will have something like:

```
<tr *ngFor="let invoice of invoiceList">
  <td>{{invoice.customer.name}} {{invoice.customer.lastname}}</td>
  <td>{{invoice.totalPrice}}</td>
  <td>{{invoice.uid}}</td>
  <td>{{invoice.createdAt}}</td>
  <td>
    <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let purchase of invoice.purchases">
      {{purchase.product.name}}
    </li>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a class="btn btn-danger text-white" (click)="onDelete(invoice.$key)">
      <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Here's the [**Updated StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/invoicing-app-sample?file=src/app/components/invoices/invoice-list/invoice-list.component.html).

Comment: in this case it only returns the value that is in position 0, and there may be more than one

Comment: Why isn't `purchases` an `array` in that case? Would it be possible to get the `purchases` as an `array` instead of an object with keys as 0, 1, 2...? If yes, make that an array.

Comment: because "purchases" has in addition to "products", has "quantity"

Comment: Check the updated answer if that helps. Will you be looping through all the purchases in the `td` elements?

Comment: Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'.

Comment: Please consider creating a stackblitz if possble. It's really hard to understand what's wrong with your implementation. The error that you're talking about generally occurs when we do an `*ngFor` on an Object instead of an Array. But I've already mapped purchases to an `Array`. Did you try it with the changed code?

Comment: What are the login credentials?

Comment: user@user.com and user123

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179578/discussion-between-siddharth-ajmera-and-rafael-antonio-corzo-gutierrez).

Answer (score 1):

Have Modified your code little bit.

```
<tr *ngFor="let invoice of invoiceList">
<td>{{invoice.customer.name}} {{invoice.customer.lastname}}</td>
<td>{{invoice.totalPrice}}</td>
<td>{{invoice.purchases["0"].product.name}}</td> //Changes are here
```

If key of an Object is a number, you have to access it like [0] or ["0"]

Hope That Helped!!